# DjangoRestFramework - Loading specific columns, and saving an entire object

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm developing an API (using DjangoRestFramework) where I want the user to be able to load a list of their items, but I only want to load a few columns from the database (let's say ID, Title, Category, and let's say the URL they are accessing is api/items).

I also want them to be able to send a POST request to this URL containing not only the columns that the page loads, but extra ones as well (example: a form with Title, Category, *Date, Rating*). If they want to view the item in full, including these extra details, they can view the individual items page (api/items/246).

From my understanding at the moment, the way you select which fields are loaded, is through a serializer class in the model's model.py file. So I have created a listSerializer and a detailSerializer, with the fields I want to load for each listed in the meta class. These work fine for getting the information I want.

My problem is when a user tries to send their POST request adding a new item: the only fields that are saved are the ones listed in the listSerializer's meta class. How can I go about saving the entire object?

Thanks in advance, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `write_only` attribute of fields to True and this will solve exactly your problem. Write only fields will not show on the response but will accept your posted data.

```
class ListSerializer (serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    title = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had a bit of difficulty using it at first, turns out I was using an older version of DjangoRestFramework.